# Using PHP tags in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if there was a way to include php tags in an external javascript file (that is included in a PHP view). 
So something like this:

```
$(function() { 

      var something = <?php echo $something_likes; ?>;
});
```

This is giving me an error.  Is this possible to do?  Or does it have to be in the PHP view.  Thank you.

Comment: don't know what the "php view is" but as php is server side it can populate any file type; just as you can write html with it you can write js

Comment: It must work if it is PHP executable file.

Comment: `<script src="myphpgeneratedjavascript.php">`

Comment: it's giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

PHP code can only run in PHP files.

Those being, files that end with the extension .php or .inc.

If you wish to print PHP code onto javascript code, you could (although not good practice) do so by putting your javascript code in a .php file and simply wrapping it in a script tag.

Just as you would with any other HTML code.

Let's call said file, myJS.php.

Inside your myJS.php, you could have something like this:

```
<script>
$(function() { 
  var something = <?php echo $something_likes; ?>;
});
</script>
```

Comment: its trivial to ask Apache to process any file as php

Answer (score -1):

You CAN'T do what you are asking here as-is. There is a slight alyernative to that. Wrap your external javascript file in a function. Let's call that `externalJsFunction`. What we can do is pass that PHP variable via a parameter to `externalJsFunction` by calling it in the page where PHP is being executef.
`/* the page where you are including your JS file and executing your PHP */
externalJsFunction("<?php echo $php_var?>");`
Hope it answers your question.

Comment: he can do what he is asking

Comment: Really? How can it be done?

Comment: I am curious as well, I am getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: look at the suggested duplicate, it gives you a number of options. if you changed the file extension to the above external file to .php then the php would run inside it fine

Comment: but I want to use it as a javascript file, there's other js in there

Comment: file extensions are meaningless it does not matter to the browser if you call it *.goat

Comment: The OP mentioned PHP view file and doing what you are suggesting, creating a JS file on the server side, is shamming the rules set forth by MVC frameworks.

Comment: who says the OP is interested in MVC?

Comment: You may want to read the question again.

Comment: I am including the js file, in a php file.  As almost all web pages do.